# How to solve the polynomial Equations?

Tags: polynomials

I'm new to this site. I have created a 6th order polynomial equation using MS Excel 2010 for fitting my data set which is given below:

```
y = -50.388x6 + 2972x5 - 72980x4 + 955030x3 - 7E+06x2 + 3E+07x - 4E+07
```

I've tried to solve this equation using MATLAB for different values of x by converting the above equation as:

```
y = -50.388*x^6 + 2972*x^5 - 72980*x^4 + 955030*x^3 - 7*10^6*x^2 + 3*10^7*x - 4*10^7
```

When solving for x = 9.5, it provided  the value of y as `y = 30570069`

But, actually that value should be 2.2.

So, how can I solve this equation? I've been using this equation in my project.

**Edited:** are there any tools that provide the polynomial equation for a given data in a `.csv` file?
Thanks.

Comment: See:http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: What `should be 2.2`?

Comment: the value of y should be 2.2 if x=9.5

Comment: How do you know it should be $2.2$?

Comment: while fitting the polynomial equation given above, I've used this (x,y) combination in the data set.

Comment: @Bikram how many data points do you have?  Maybe Excel was just doing regression rather than interpolation.  I'd be curious to see your .csv file.

Comment: I've upload the file content in the link: http://codepad.org/TL5tMJ1z

Comment: @MarkBennet actually the deviation in the solution was due to the rounding off in  the coefficients of x. It was taking upto 4th place only.After removing the round off the equation gave the 100% accurate result .Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *first-order term* is $4\cdot 10^7 \, x$, given with only one significant digit. When $x$ is around $10$, this gives an uncertainty in the intended function value of about $10^8$, and the difference between $2.2$ and $30570069$ is well within this tolerance.

And there's a similarly-sized uncertainty contribution from the second-order term.

Perhaps a polynomial approximation is not exactly what will serve you best in your situation? Depending on what the data you're trying to fit are, it might be better if you try to do a polynomial fit of the *logarithms* of the desired values.

Comment: +1: Nicely illustrates the difference between real numbers and floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some Matlab code that fits a polynomial to your data and checks that the results look reasonable.

```
data = ...
[8.55   0.4;...
9       0.46;...
9.05    1.46;...
9.1     2.07;...
9.15    1.65;...
9.2     1.35;...
9.25    1.4;...
9.3     1.43;...
9.35    1.4;...
9.4     2.1;...
9.5     2.2;...
9.55    2.7;...
10      3.2;...
10.05   3.5;...
10.1    3.4;...
10.15   2.9;...
10.2    2.8;...
10.25   2.7;...
10.3    2.1;...
10.35   2.5;...
10.4    2.6;...
10.45   3;...
10.5    3.5;...
10.55   3.1;...
11      3.2;...
11.05   2.58;...
11.1    3.08;...
11.15   3.07;...
11.2    3.27;...
11.25   3.13;...
11.3    2.44;...
11.35   1.4];

x = data(:,1);
y = data(:,2);
n = 6;
p = polyfit(x,y,n);
yEst = polyval(p,x);

figure
plot(x,y)
hold all
plot(x,yEst)
```